# Get all documents from a sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint, document

I want to retrieve all documents from an SPDocumentLibrary I've tried this way but then I got stucked

```
using (SPSite mysite = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    using (SPWeb myweb = mysite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPDocumentLibrary myDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)myweb.Lists["DocLibrary"];
        SPList myList = SPContext.Current.List;
        SPFileCollection myFiles = myList.;
        foreach (SPListItem myItem in myList.Items)
        {
            //adding each found file to my SPFileCollection
            myFiles.Add(myItem.File);
        }
    }
}
```

but the SPFileCollection.Add function takes more than the file argument !

Comment: Yes, you need to provide the contents of the file if you want to add it to that collection.  Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Also, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask about SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

*If I had to guess*: you don't actually want to add them to a `SPFileCollection`.  Doing this means that you're copying the files, but without using the convenient Copy method.

You probably just want to store them temporarily in a `List<SPFile>` or similar.

There are a lot of classes in the SharePoint object library called Collections, but they are not meant to be used like classes in the Systems.Collections namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Once Again

[link here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/48959/get-all-documents-from-a-sharepoint-document-library)

```
 public static bool getAllDocuments()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("getAllDocuments debug, START");
     bool isOK = false;
     string baseUrl = "http://jabdw3421:82/sites/TestSite/";
     try
     {
         SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
         {
             using (SPSite site = new SPSite(baseUrl))
             {
                 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                 {
                     SPDocumentLibrary lib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["TestLib"];
                     IEnumerable<SPFile> allFiles = ExploreFolder(lib.RootFolder);

                     foreach (SPFile file in allFiles)
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("getAllDocuments debug, File Name : " + file.Name);
                         Console.WriteLine("getAllDocuments debug, File CharSetName : " + file.CharSetName);
                         Console.WriteLine("getAllDocuments debug, File SourceLeafName : " + file.SourceLeafName);
                     }
                 }
             }
         });
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("getAllDocuments debug, " + e.Message);
         isOK = false;
     }
     Console.WriteLine("getAllDocuments debug, END");
     return isOK;
 }

 private static IEnumerable<SPFile> ExploreFolder(SPFolder folder)
 {
     foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
     {
         yield return file;
     }
     foreach (SPFolder subFolder in folder.SubFolders)
     {
         foreach (SPFile file in ExploreFolder(subFolder))
         {
             yield return file;
         }
     }
 }
```